# What is the difference between glfwGetWindowSize and glfwGetFramebufferSize?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I am learning opengl and I am using the glfw library. I trying to understand what the documentation means screen coordinate and the framebuffer of a window. Hence, I logged the width and height output of both of these functions but they are identical to each other.

So I am not so sure what is the difference between glfwGetWindowSize and glfwGetFramebufferSize.

Also, can I have a clarification on what is the difference between framebuffer size and the size of the window in screen coordinates? (Both of these two size are mentioned in the documentation but have no explanation. Furthermore, these two size corresponds to glfwGetFramebufferSize and glfwGetWindowSize respectively).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GLFW explains both coordinate systems in there documentation [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_fbsize) and [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#coordinate_systems).

In short, window coordinates are relative to the monitor and/or the window and are given in artificial units that do not necessarily correspond to real screen pixels. This is especially the case when dpi scaling is activated (for example, on Macs with retina display).

Framebuffer sizes are, in contrast to the window coordinates, given in pixels in order to match OpenGLs requirements for `glViewport`.

Note, that on some systems window coordinates and pixel coordinates can be the same but this is not necessarily true.

Comment: Hi, I think your answer was helpful but just a quick clarification. So If I have a dpi of 1 then my screen coordinates will be the same as my frame buffer correct? This explains why on my screen, the window's screen coordinate = the window framebuffer right?

Comment: In general: Yes. There could also be some differences in full-screen applications with a non-native resolution. In the end, it will depend on the OS and the exact hardware/software configuration. When writing an application you should assume that these two sizes are not the same.

Comment: Hello, I've checked GLFW source code and saw that `glfwGetFramebufferSize` is literally defined as `glfwGetWindowSize` for Win32 platform.. why are they exactly the same on Windows?